# running batch process over file named in unicode

Tags: batch-file

I need to run a process over file named in unicode ?
How using a batch file ?

I tried :

```
 dir /b %folder% > dir.lst

 ::cmd /u /c dir /b %folder% > dir.lst
 FOR /F "delims= tokens=*" %%G IN (dir.lst) DO ( 
 echo %%G
 @set filename2=%%G
 @echo %filename2%


 @set filename=%pathlogs%\!filename2!
 @echo %filename%
 @echo %filename2%
 @%binaries%\gawk -v fn=%filename% -v fn2=%filename2% -f %scripts%\AlexBank_barcode.awk                               %folder%\%filename2% 2> %scripts%\AlexBank_barcode.fil
 @%binaries%\sort -k 1.129,1.144 -T F:\tmp  %pathlogs%\%filename2%.log >      %pathlogs%\%filename2%.log.tmp 2> %scripts%\%filename2%".sort.fil"
 @set filename3=%filename%.log.tmp1
 @%binaries%\gawk -f %scripts%\AlexBank_collect_barcode.awk %pathlogs%\%filename2%.log.tmp 2> %scripts%\AlexBank_collect_barcode.fil
 @set filename3=%filename%.separate_all.log
 @%binaries%\gawk -f %scripts%\AlexBank_separate_barcode.awk %pathlogs%\%filename2%.log.tmp1 2> %scripts%\AlexBank_separate_barcode.fil

 @set filename3=%filename%.separate_statement_le.awk.log
```

@%binaries%\gawk -v fn=%filename3% -f %scripts%\AlexBank_separate_statement_le.awk      %pathlogs%\%filename2%.log.tmp1 2>      %scripts%\%filename2%".AlexBank_separate_statement_le.awk.fil"
     @set filename3=%filename%.separate_statement_gt.awk.log
     @%binaries%\gawk -v fn=%filename3% -f %scripts%\AlexBank_separate_statement_gt.awk      %pathlogs%\%filename2%.log.tmp1 2>      %scripts%\%filename2%".AlexBank_separate_statement_gt.awk.fil"
     )

Comment: Please describe the problem you encountered.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options here:

1. Set a TrueType font for your console window
2. Don't use `for /f` to iterate over the output of `dir /b`. It's unnecessary in the vast majority of cases, more complicated to get right, more brittle and fails on Unicode file names when the settings are slightly wrong as you experience. You can use `for` to iterate over files directly:

   ```
   for %%F in (%folder%\*) do ...
   ```